# Is it possible to delete numbering <ol> in tinymce

Tags: tinymce

I wanna to delete numbering in tinymce . Is it even possible ?

When I write `1.` then press `enter` it automaticaly add `2.` I dont want it

Answer (score 0):

If you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> a second time the number goes away and you exit the list.  What behavior would you want while in a list and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> once?  The creation of the next list element is standard behavior across word processors and rich text editors.